# POST Integers PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post, integer

I am using a POST method with AJAX to send an integer value from a form to the php script to be inserted into a database. When I do this the value is always zero when I cast it e.g `$int = (int)$_POST['total'];` and `$int = intval($_POST['total']);` and when I do not cast it the $int variable is assigned a string, when I `var_dump` the `$_POST` i get `array(1) { ["int"]=> string(2) "20" }` returned to the screen. does anybody know how to help me?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please review your question and be more specific when saying when doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your variable is located in `$_POST['int']` and not in `$_POST['total']`. So change the `name` attribute or the php to correct that.

Comment: Brilliant, you have saved me from never ending stress, thank you.

Comment: If you add error_reporting(E_ALL) to the top of your scripts, PHP will raise a Notice when it finds something like this and you won't have to guess about it :-)

Comment: @RayPaseur Thanks will be doing this from now on